# Why doesn't the response of URL get displayed using Scrapy but gets displayed using Requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the results of this API from [here](https://www.kap.org.tr/en/api/memberDisclosureQuery). When I use requests to get the contents of this I get a proper output. But when I try to run it in scrapy, I fail to get the response.
here's the code using requests which gives me a definite response.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.kap.org.tr/en/api/memberDisclosureQuery'
payload = {
        "fromDate":"2021-06-08",
        "toDate":"2021-06-14",
        "year":"",
        "prd":"",
        "term":"",
        "ruleType":"",
        "bdkReview":"",
        "disclosureClass":"",
        "index":"",
        "market":"",
        "isLate":"",
        "subjectList":["4028328c594bfdca01594c0af9aa0057","4028328d6233239a01629b674aeb5631"],
        "mkkMemberOidList":[],
        "inactiveMkkMemberOidList":[],
        "bdkMemberOidList":[],
        "mainSector":"",
        "sector":"",
        "subSector":"",
        "memberType":"IGS",
        "fromSrc":"N",
        "srcCategory":"",
        "discIndex":[]
    }

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).text
```

I get the output as desired.

```
[{"publishDate":"Yesterday 18:25","kapTitle":"EGE PROFİL TİCARET VE SANAYİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":942256,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"EGPRO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1,"isModified":"DUZELTME"},{"publishDate":"10.06.21 07:49","kapTitle":"GÜLER YATIRIM HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31.03.2021 mali tablo","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941618,"isLate":true,"stockCodes":"GLRYH","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 22:53","kapTitle":"RTA LABORATUVARLARI BİYOLOJİK ÜRÜNLER İLAÇ VE MAKİNE SANAYİ TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31.03.2021 Mali Tablo hk","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941593,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"RTALB","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 22:44","kapTitle":"DİRİTEKS DİRİLİŞ TEKSTİL SANAYİ  VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941592,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"DIRIT","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 22:23","kapTitle":"MEGA POLİETİLEN KÖPÜK SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"2021 1. Dönem Finansal Raporlar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941588,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"MEGAP","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 21:24","kapTitle":"İHLAS HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941583,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"IHLAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 21:20","kapTitle":"İHLAS GAYRİMENKUL PROJE GELİŞTİRME VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941579,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"IHLGM","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 21:17","kapTitle":"İHLAS YAYIN HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941575,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"IHYAY","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 21:13","kapTitle":"OSTİM ENDÜSTRİYEL YATIRIMLAR VE İŞLETME A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941572,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"OSTIM","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 21:05","kapTitle":"COSMOS YATIRIM HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31/03/2021 Konsolide Mali Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941569,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"COSMO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:50","kapTitle":"GSD HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941566,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"GSDHO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:46","kapTitle":"SÖKTAŞ TEKSTİL SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941563,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SKTAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:38","kapTitle":"ÖZBAL ÇELİK BORU SANAYİ TİCARET VE TAAHHÜT A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941560,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"OZBAL","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:18","kapTitle":"ADESE GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31.03.2021 Mali Tablo ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941557,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ADESE","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:17","kapTitle":"ÜNLÜ YATIRIM HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Ünlü Yatırım Holding A.Ş. 31.03.2021 Konsolide Finansal Tablolar ve Dipnotlar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941556,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"UNLU","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 20:12","kapTitle":"İTTİFAK HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31.03.2021 Mali Tablo ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941551,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ITTFH","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:49","kapTitle":"PARSAN MAKİNA PARÇALARI SANAYİİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941547,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"PARSN","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:35","kapTitle":"SİNPAŞ GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 Dönemi Finansal Raporlar ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941544,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SNGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:34","kapTitle":"SİNPAŞ GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 Dönemi Finansal Raporlar ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941543,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SNGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:25","kapTitle":"KUYUMCUKENT GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIMLARI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941540,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"KUYAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:21","kapTitle":"BURÇELİK BURSA ÇELİK DÖKÜM SANAYİİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021-31.03.2021 Dönemi Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941528,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"BURCE","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:12","kapTitle":"SAN-EL MÜHENDİSLİK ELEKTRİK TAAHHÜT SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Tablolar (31.03.2021)","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941525,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SANEL","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:07","kapTitle":"ÜNLÜ MENKUL DEĞERLER A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Ünlü Menkul Değerler A.Ş. 31.03.2021 Konsolide Finansal Tablolar ve Dipnotlar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941524,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"UNLUS, UNS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 19:00","kapTitle":"TURCAS PETROL A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"TURCAS PETROL A.Ş. 01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 DÖNEMİ TFRS RAPOR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941519,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"TRCAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:38","kapTitle":"BAGFAŞ BANDIRMA GÜBRE FABRİKALARI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"2021 Yılı 1. Çeyrek Konsolide Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941509,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"BAGFS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:33","kapTitle":"MAVİ GİYİM SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"February 1- April 30, 2021 Financial Results ","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941503,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"MAVI","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:31","kapTitle":"İZMİR FIRÇA SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"2021 Yılı 1. 3 Aylık Dönem Finansal Tabloları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941498,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"IZFAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:28","kapTitle":"YEŞİL GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"YGYO 31.03.2021 BİREYSEL MALİ TABLOLAR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941495,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"YGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:28","kapTitle":"YEŞİL GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"YGYO 31.03.2021 MALİ TABLO VE DİPNOTLARI","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941493,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"YGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:19","kapTitle":"TERA YATIRIM MENKUL DEĞERLER A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Tera Yatırım Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941486,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"STK, TRMNK","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:17","kapTitle":"GSD DENİZCİLİK GAYRİMENKUL İNŞAAT SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"31.03.2021 Konsolide Finansal Tablolar ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941481,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"GSDDE","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:16","kapTitle":"EMEK ELEKTRİK ENDÜSTRİSİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021-31.03.2021 Mali Tablo ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941479,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"EMKEL","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:16","kapTitle":"NET HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Tablo Dipnot Açıklamaları ekte \"pdf\" dosya olarak yer almaktadır.","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941477,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"NTHOL","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:14","kapTitle":"BİRLİK MENSUCAT TİCARET VE SANAYİ İŞLETMESİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"BRMEN Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941472,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"BRMEN","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:14","kapTitle":"SEKURO PLASTİK AMBALAJ SANAYİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 Finansal Tablolar Hk.","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941469,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SEKUR","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:14","kapTitle":"KONYA ÇİMENTO SANAYİİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Konya Çimento Sanayii A.Ş. 31.03.2021 Konsolide Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941468,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"KONYA","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:11","kapTitle":"KÜTAHYA PORSELEN SANAYİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"2021 Yılı 1. 3 Aylık Dönem Finansal Tablolar Hk.","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941463,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"KUTPO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"09.06.21 18:11","kapTitle":"PHİLLİPCAPİTAL MENKUL DEĞERLER A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Konsolide Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941461,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"PHC, PHLLP","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 21:33","kapTitle":"CEO EVENT MEDYA A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021-31.03.2021 DÖNEMİ MALİ TABLOLAR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941263,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"CEOEM","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 20:16","kapTitle":"GLOBAL YATIRIM HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941258,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"GLYHO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 20:15","kapTitle":"PENTA TEKNOLOJİ ÜRÜNLERİ DAĞITIM TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Konsolide Finansal Tablolar ve Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941256,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"PENTA","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 19:27","kapTitle":"SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021-31.03.2021 Solo Mali Tablolar ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941244,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SRVGY","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 19:27","kapTitle":"SERVET GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021-31.03.2021 Dönemi Konsolide Mali Tablolar ve Dipnotları","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941243,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SRVGY","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 19:26","kapTitle":"SENKRON GÜVENLİK VE İLETİŞİM SİSTEMLERİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Raporlar (31.03.2021)","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941242,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"SNKRN","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 19:05","kapTitle":"ZİRAAT GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Konsolide Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941236,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ZRGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 19:02","kapTitle":"ZİRAAT GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941235,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ZRGYO","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:30","kapTitle":"TAÇ TARIM ÜRÜNLERİ HAYVANCILIK GIDA SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"2021 1.Dönem Mali Raporlar ","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941225,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"TACTR","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:26","kapTitle":"İZ HAYVANCILIK TARIM VE GIDA SANAYİ TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941220,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"IZTAR","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:24","kapTitle":"REYSAŞ TAŞIMACILIK VE LOJİSTİK TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941217,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"RYSAS","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:18","kapTitle":"ULUSOY ELEKTRİK İMALAT TAAHHÜT VE TİCARET A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941207,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ULUSE","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:12","kapTitle":"ARSAN TEKSTİL TİCARET VE SANAYİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 Tarihli Konsolide Finansal Tablolar","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941200,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"ARSAN","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:11","kapTitle":"RAL YATIRIM HOLDİNG A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"Finansal Rapor","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941198,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"RALYH","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1},{"publishDate":"08.06.21 18:11","kapTitle":"HATEKS HATAY TEKSTİL İŞLETMELERİ A.Ş.","isOldKap":false,"disclosureClass":"FR","disclosureType":"FR","disclosureCategory":"FR","summary":"01.01.2021 - 31.03.2021 FİNANSAL RAPORLAR","subject":"Financial Report","year":2021,"ruleTypeTerm":"3 Months","disclosureIndex":941196,"isLate":false,"stockCodes":"HATEK","hasMultiLanguageSupport":true,"attachmentCount":1}]
```

with Scrapy..this doesn't work. here's the code.

```
class TurkishSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kap'
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
    items = PubMonitorItem()
    allowed_domains = ['kap.org.tr']
    payload = {
        "fromDate":"2021-06-08",
        "toDate":"2021-06-14",
        "year":"",
        "prd":"",
        "term":"",
        "ruleType":"",
        "bdkReview":"",
        "disclosureClass":"",
        "index":"",
        "market":"",
        "isLate":"",
        "subjectList":["4028328c594bfdca01594c0af9aa0057","4028328d6233239a01629b674aeb5631"],
        "mkkMemberOidList":[],
        "inactiveMkkMemberOidList":[],
        "bdkMemberOidList":[],
        "mainSector":"",
        "sector":"",
        "subSector":"",
        "memberType":"IGS",
        "fromSrc":"N",
        "srcCategory":"",
        "discIndex":[]
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.kap.org.tr/en/api/memberDisclosureQuery'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, method="POST", body=json.dumps(TurkishSpider.payload))

    def parse(self, response):
        self.crawler.stats.set_value("spider_name", self.name)
        print(response.text)
```

when run using scrapy krawl kap it gives me an output like

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:30%;margin-top:10%">
<a href="https:/www.kap.org.tr"><img src="https://www.kap.org.tr/assets/images/errors/hata_500_transparent.png" style="border:none"/></a>
<font face=arial />
<p>Yasadiginiz bu erisim problemini "134784817-PPE1" hata numarasi ile </p>
<p>kapdestek@mkk.com.tr adresine bildirebilirsiniz.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After checking the logs this is the root cause of not getting the desired output.

```
2021-06-15 14:41:02 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <POST https://www.kap.org.tr/en/api/memberDisclosureQuery> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy_splash/middleware.py", line 156, in process_spider_output
    for el in result:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/technophile/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/mnt/f/ABC/XYZ/abc/abc/spiders/turkey.py", line 63, in parse
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2021-06-15 14:41:02 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I've been trying to get the response printed using scrapy since Friday, but nothing so far has worked. Please, Please help me.

Comment: Did you try specifying the content type in the request?
`headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}`

Comment: @AmosBaker : Yes, I've tried that as well. Nothing seems to be working.